# Java Guice: Deep object injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have classes B, C, and D. Just now, I want to add a class A whose attributes are wholly bound to values in an app config. What's the best practice in using Guice to inject the values into class A?

```
public class A {
    public A(@Named("id") String id, ..., @Named("attr") String attr) {
        ....
    }   
}

public class B {
    public B() {
        this.a = new A();
    }
}


 public class C {
    public C() {
         this.b = new B();
    }
 }

 public class D {

     @Inject
     private Injector injector;

     public D() {
          this.c = new C();
     }
 }
```

One possibility I can think of is to keep passing Injector instance from D to B and change B s.t.:

```
public class B {
    public B(Injector injector) {
        this.a = injector.getInstance(A.class);
    }
}
```

This seems bad form and I have not seen online examples using this. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

rather than `new`'ing `A`, `B`, and `C`, why not require them to be passed in as dependencies. something like this:

```
class A {
    private final String id;
    private final String attr;

    @Inject
    A(String id, String attr) {
        this.id   = id;
        this.attr = attr;
    }
}

class B {
    private final A a;

    @Inject
    B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}


class C {
    private final B b;

    @Inject
    C(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class D {
    private final C c;

    @Inject
    D(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

and then use Guice to create and inject the instances as needed:

```
@Module
public class Module {
    @Provides
    public A provideA(@Named("id") String id, @Named("attr") String attr) {
        return A(id, attr);
    }

    @Provides 
    public B provideB(A a) {
        return new B(a);
    }

    @Provides 
    public C provideC(B b) {
        return new C(b);
    }

    @Provides 
    public D provideD(C c) {
        return new D(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree with the answer as a whole (+1 from me), I would still make it clear that each constructor is the one expected to be injected, and add the `@Inject` to each of those.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire agreed (this is also how i typically write my code). updated to reflect the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry to ask (first day using Guice here) - How do you create D then? injector.getInstance(D.class)? What if I want to just create B in another object? How do I get the Injector in scope?

Comment: @user1836155 Yes, exactly like that!

Comment: @user1836155 that depends on the context - normally you're working in the context of some framework and you register the IoC container with the framework. Then the framework takes care of resolving top-level components. If not, you do it like that in the root of your application.

Comment: The only time you wouldn't is if you need to pump the objects out like crazy fast for performance. In which case, just make a factory that produces them without guice, that takes what the factory needs to make them using guice. At some point in the tree you will have objects that arn't getting made quick enough to need to avoid DI

Comment: +1 to the concept, though notably the Module example is in Dagger style (`@Module`). A Guice equivalent would drop the annotation, extend AbstractModule, and have a `configure` method (that could be empty).